# D-Link DWA-131 Wi-Fi USB stick scans, but does not connects on 20.04

Tags: wireless

I've got trouble with embedded Wi-Fi on old HP laptop [WiFi hard blocked on HP 15-ac002ur on Ubuntu 20.04 and nothing helps](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1351309/wifi-hard-blocked-on-hp-15-ac002ur-on-ubuntu-20-04-and-nothing-helps) and could not solve it so I've bought Wi-Fi USB stick D-Link DWA-131 but got trouble with it too.

Wi-Fi USB stick is recognized:

```
[08:06]dmitriy@dmitriy-HP-Notebook[~]$ dmesg | tail
[ 1154.683426] usb 1-5.2: 1d8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1154.683429] usb 1-5.2: 1e0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1154.683431] usb 1-5.2: 1e8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1154.683434] usb 1-5.2: 1f0: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1154.683437] usb 1-5.2: 1f8: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
[ 1154.683442] usb 1-5.2: RTL8192EU rev B (SMIC) 2T2R, TX queues 3, WiFi=1, BT=0, GPS=0, HI PA=0
[ 1154.683446] usb 1-5.2: RTL8192EU MAC: 18:0f:76:09:dc:de
[ 1154.683449] usb 1-5.2: rtl8xxxu: Loading firmware rtlwifi/rtl8192eu_nic.bin
[ 1154.683585] usb 1-5.2: Firmware revision 19.0 (signature 0x92e1)
[ 1155.722333] rtl8xxxu 1-5.2:1.0 wlx180f7609dcde: renamed from wlan0
```

`rfkill` does not show blocked status:

```
[08:06]dmitriy@dmitriy-HP-Notebook[~]$ rfkill list
0: phy1: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: yes
2: phy2: Wireless LAN
        Soft blocked: no
        Hard blocked: no
```

Interface is up:

```
[08:07]dmitriy@dmitriy-HP-Notebook[~]$ ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: enp3s0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 48:0f:cf:de:e9:15 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
3: wlp2s0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether d8:5d:e2:4d:ec:ee brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
5: wlx180f7609dcde: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state DOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 18:0f:76:09:dc:de brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
```

And scan is successful:

```
[08:08]dmitriy@dmitriy-HP-Notebook[~]$ sudo iwlist wlx180f7609dcde scan | head -20
wlx180f7609dcde  Scan completed :
          Cell 01 - Address: A0:AB:1B:2C:A3:69
                    Channel:1
                    Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                    Quality=22/70  Signal level=-88 dBm  
                    Encryption key:on
                    ESSID:"MTSRouter-2CA369"
...
```

But `nmcli` shows that interface is disabled:

```
[08:08]dmitriy@dmitriy-HP-Notebook[~]$ nmcli 
...
wlx180f7609dcde: unavailable
        "D-Link Nano"
        wifi (rtl8xxxu), 18:0F:76:09:DC:DE, sw disabled, hw, mtu 1500
...
```

Tried `nmcli radio wifi on` - same thing.

Tried to create connection, but `nmcli` shows that device is not available:

```
[08:18]dmitriy@dmitriy-HP-Notebook[~]$ nmcli connection up "Wi-Fi connection 1" ifname wlx180f7609dcde
Error: Connection activation failed: Connection 'Wi-Fi connection 1' is not available on device wlx180f7609dcde because device is not available
```

Tried to access without NetworkManager (disabled it with `systemctl`) manually with wpa supplicant, it shows (I'm sure that password is correct):

```
[08:13]dmitriy@dmitriy-HP-Notebook[~]$ sudo wpa_supplicant -i wlx180f7609dcde -c wpa-2.conf 
Successfully initialized wpa_supplicant
wlx180f7609dcde: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:5e:a4:1d:d2:5a (SSID='netis_2.4G_1DD253' freq=2422 MHz)
wlx180f7609dcde: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:5e:a4:1d:d2:5a (SSID='netis_2.4G_1DD253' freq=2422 MHz)
wlx180f7609dcde: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:5e:a4:1d:d2:5a (SSID='netis_2.4G_1DD253' freq=2422 MHz)
wlx180f7609dcde: SME: Trying to authenticate with 04:5e:a4:1d:d2:5a (SSID='netis_2.4G_1DD253' freq=2422 MHz)
wlx180f7609dcde: CTRL-EVENT-SSID-TEMP-DISABLED id=0 ssid="netis_2.4G_1DD253" auth_failures=1 duration=10 reason=CONN_FAILED
```

So seems that I'm close to solution but don't know how to make final step.

Could anybody help?

Comment: You have not said what you have purchased and do you know for sure Ubuntu supports it?

Comment: It is D-Link DWA-131, updated post. Not sure, just researching.

Answer (score 0):

Found my own question about same Wi-Fi USB stick and same old laptop [D-Link DWA-131 does not work in Ubuntu 18.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1069137/d-link-dwa-131-does-not-work-in-ubuntu-18-04) (I gave up at those time and forgotten about answer posted there), blacklisted `rtl8188ee` and now Wi-Fi works with module `rtl8xxxu`.